# 240v/200v between hot and neutral,24-41v between hot and hot

Tags: electrical, 240v

yesterday our power went off. No break in the circuit board. One of the lights still works.

But let me explain the house. It's very small, probably 12x4m. Our bedroom is closest to the circuit board. The light works there. No Plugs in this room. Next room is the kitchen, one plug, one light, not coming on. Next room one plug one light, not coming on.

Testing one of the plugs in the rooms I get the following:

240v from black to ground ???
200v from red to ground ???
red to black alternates between 25 and 42v???

Very weird!

What could be the cause of this? Really need help, it's a public holiday, we stay in the middle of nowhere and everything is going to unfreeze soon.

Everything is unplugged at the moment.

Comment: What nation are you in?  If in 120V North America, CO, Venezuela, Ecuador, JP or the 120V part of PH, you may have a broken neutral wire in the panel or supply.   This is very dangerous and call the power company immediately and report an outage.   ------- If in the 230V rest of the world sounds like you have 2 hots and one has failed.  The other should work.

Comment: South Africa - I figured out the problem and fixed it! After removing almost the whole zink roof. There was a live wire that melted and touched earth. Why didn't this short the break? Anyways, happy its working now. We will get someone to come and make sure the wiring in the house is safe....